# song history needed from api

Tags: javascript, html, json

i need the song history text and art from this api: https://azuracast.web-radio.nl/api/nowplaying/2

i want to remake this because this works for the currently song and art:

```
function getAPI() {
    $.getJSON("https://azuracast.web-radio.nl/api/nowplaying/2", function(data){
        //
        var art = data.now_playing.song.art;
        $('.art').attr('style', 'background-image: url(\''+art+'\'); border-radius:15px; height:150px; background-size: cover;');
        //
        var artist = data.now_playing.song.text;
        var title = data.now_playing.streamer;
        var album = data.now_playing.song.art;
        if(album != '') {
            var formatted =  title+'  '+artist;
        } else { 
            var formatted =  title+'   '+artist;
        }
        $('.song').text(formatted);
        setTimeout(getAPI,1);
    });
}
getAPI();
```

But suddenly when i change "data.now_playing.song.text;" to "data.song_history.song.text;" and "data.now_playing.song.art" to "data.song_history.song.art"

it doesn't work.

does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Without the definition of the API, or at least some sample data we can't tell. I speculate the `song_history` returns more than one song, so you'll need to update your code to accommodate it. There's not enough information here to say what changes are needed. See [ask]

Comment: sorry i want  a song history with art. the same as the script above but then for song history and the art. the script above works as what currently is playing but then i need the same but then for the history. like what played before

Comment: `song_history` is an array. `now_playing` is an object.

Comment: @Andorbird I understand what you want but you haven't provided enough information for us to help you. Read my comment above again, the see the page I've linked to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)